# Get model position from drop in ckedtior 5

Tags: ckeditor5

I have a listener on drop event

```
documentView.on('drop',function(event, data) {
    // I need the model position here, so I can insert an element at this position.
}
```

And that works fine. My function gets called on drop. The question is: How do I get the model position for the drop so I use it in an insert operation with the writer?

data got a dropRange field, but it's a view range, not a model range and I can't find any way to convert the view range/position to a model range/position.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try below code

```
documentView.on('drop', function (event, data) {
    // Assuming `editor` is your ProseMirror editor instance
    const editor = // your editor instance;

    // Convert the view position to a model position
    const dropPosition = editor.posAtCoords({ left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY });

    // Now you can use dropPosition to perform your insert operation
    editor.transaction((tr) => {
        tr.insert(dropPosition.pos, // your content);
        // You might need to update the selection or perform other operations here
        editor.view.dispatch(tr);
    });

    // Make sure to prevent the default drop behavior
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

editor.posAtCoords({ left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY }) is used to convert the client coordinates of the drop event to a ProseMirror model position.

If you're not using ProseMirror, the specific methods and APIs might be different, so you'll need to refer to the documentation of your editor library for the correct way to convert view positions to model positions.

Comment: I am confused. It seems like ProseMirror is a different editor from ckedtior 5 ??